# Creating/Integrating an XCode project

Tags: iphone, xcode

is there any way to create an XCode project without using XCode?
I want to create an XCode project from scratch i.e. I want to put together some .m & .h files and create a project that would run in XCode.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "without using Xcode"?

If you mean writing your own program that builds Xcode project documents completely independent of Xcode, you could reverse engineer the Xcode project file format. The Xcode project file format is rather simple.  It's a package with a few XML like text based data files.  The format is not documented, so you'd have to reverse engineer the file format.  It sounds like a nice hobby that will greatly assist you in procrastinating from completing the actual project.

If you mean creating an Xcode project without manually operating the Xcode GUI, you could write an AppleScript script to automate the process.  Xcode has an extensive AppleScript dictionary, allowing you to fully script the creation of an Xcode project and populate it with some .m and .h files.

Comment: thanx a lot. can u suggest some blogs/tutorials which i can refer to make my own project. "without using xcode" i meant that i put together some files and folders and that should build in xcode, without actually using the new project wizard to create a project.